# Share panorama image

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, 360-panorama

I'm trying share panorama photo with FBSDKShareDialog but it does not identified as panorama photo in share dialog and in Facebook Feed after sharing. But if I save this photo to Camera Roll or in pc with AirDrop, and just share with facebook app or drag'n'drop to facebook.com it shared like panorama.
I add all needed exif (XMP) metadata that need for facebook.
In code i share with this:

```
let photoContent = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
var photos:[FBSDKSharePhoto] = []

for url in urls {
    if let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto(imageURL: url, userGenerated: true){
        photos.append(photo)
    }
}
photoContent.photos = photos
        photoContent.addParameters(["allow_spherical_photo":true], bridgeOptions: .init(rawValue: 0))

let dialog = FBSDKShareDialog()

dialog.mode = .automatic
dialog.shareContent = photoContent
dialog.fromViewController = viewController
dialog.delegate = self
dialog.show()
```

link to photo that I trying to share
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1R0SemvHL85GMy-kY8--uNWzSDH-3oMDD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Most likely the share dialog doesn't support panorama then

Comment: @WizKid so at this moment no ways for share panorama photos from app? As I understand from 1 August 2018 we can't request permission 'publish_actions' for using GraphApi for post images?